# Java equivalent of C# Action.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, java, delegates, begininvoke

I have this C# code:

```
Action action = MyFunction;
action.BeginInvoke(action.EndInvoke, action);
```

which, from what I can tell, just runs MyFunction asynchronously. Can you do the same thing in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you could run an action in its own thread in Java:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        aFunctionThatRunsAsynchronously();
    }
}).start();
```

There are other higher-level frameworks available that give you more control on how things are run such as [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), which can for example be used to [schedule events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: `BeginInvoke` will use the thread pool, is there such a concept in Java? - Sorry, I should have taken a second to follow your "Executors" link! Thanks

Comment: When I try this I get the error "The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method".

Comment: @adam0101 Not sure why: it works on my machine. What version of Java JDK are you using? If you use Java 5 or earlier, you might need to remove the `@Override` annotation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135975/can-i-get-java-5-to-ignore-override-errors).

Answer (score 2):

Natively, the ExecutorService provides the closest I can think of. Here's how you can use the ExecutorService to run a method async and then get the return value later:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    return getSomeLongRunningSomethingHere();
});
//... do other stuff here
String rtnValue = future.get(); //get blocks until the original finishes running 
System.out.println(rtnValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat related to [Asynchronous Event Dispatch in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112599/asynchronous-event-dispatch-in-java). Basically, you can structure the method you want to run as a class implementing Callable or Runnable. Java doesn't have the ability to refer to a "method group" as a variable or parameter, like C# does, so even event handlers in Java are classes implementing an interface defining the listener.

Try something like this:

```
Executor scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

//You'd have to change MyFunction to be a class implementing Callable or Runnable
scheduler.submit(MyFunction);
```

More reading from the Oracle Java docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html